# How to avoid going to a user for access token generation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am writing a server which connects to a facebook account on behalf of a corporation, so the account is known and fixed.

The method my prototype code uses to access the facebook feed is as follows

1) use a WebBrowser UI component top request https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth with client_id (AKA AppID) and redirect_uri parameters passed.  When this returns it either returns an access token or, if this is not cached by the web browser, prompts the user to login. If this is successful the Web Browser response is fired with the access token.

From there I 
2) check the access token is application to the app, and then 
3) generate a longer life token from that. 
4) read the feed
It seems to work OK.

However my problem is that when I turn this into server code, there will be no user.  So when the access token is not known I have no way of getting it.

Is there a way around this??

Thanks.

Comment: there has to be user interaction to login using oauth

Comment: It seems I have a problem then. This server is intended to access a facebook account, analyse the posts on there and produce reports which are then emailed to nominated recipients.  Is there no way to do this without direct user interaction?   There is some nuance in your answer which suggests it could be possible if I did not log in with oauth?  Is there another way?

Comment: Also, how come mobile apps which access facebook never ask the user to log in - but run perpetually ?

Comment: Those mobile apps DO ask for credentials the first time they get executed, then request a long live access token, stored it and make calls using it.... and if that token gets revoked or expired, they ask for new ones. / If you app read post from a "Facebook Page", then you can generate the long live access token once and then keep using it (they will never expire)